# Credentials for hired web developer on Amazon EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I am hosting a wordpress website on Amazon EC2. I used keypair (.pem) to access the directories using FileZilla. 
How can I give a hired web developer an access to the directories? 
Is it ok to give a copy of .pem to him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is have the developer generate their own SSH key. When they do this, it will generate both a public and private key file. All you need to do is add the public key file to a file called authorized_keys for the user you want to give them access to within the instance.

You will find the file in the home directory of the user within `.ssh`

Comment: You mean to generate public key and private key, the developer has to create his own aws account? Can I create new key pairs using my account and send it to him?

Comment: Not at all. All they need is their own ssh key pair. Linux and OS X have a tool already installed. Can use putty on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your AWS console, click services, and then click IAM (Identity and Access Management). The best way to give the web developer access to the directory would be to create a new user in the IAM console and then assign that user specific permissions. By doing this, you can grant the developer access to EC2 while restricting them to areas that you do not want changed (billing, other AWS services). After creating the user, you can download a specific keypair specific to that user. Never give out your keypair to other users.

To allow another user access to your EC2 instance, add their keypair that was generated from their specific user account to `.ssh/authorized_keys`. You can either SSH into the instance and add the key to the file mentioned or click "connect" when viewing the instance in the AWS console. Please look at this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html for adding users to your EC2 instance.

Check out this link for more info about how to setup a new user with AWS - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_controlling-access.html

For information regarding what IAM is, checkout http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/

Comment: This covers access to AWS services, but does not SSH keys on a specific instance.